# bring levels of second list item of pandas groupy into a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have the following `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Team": ["Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Red Sox", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees", "Yankees"],
        "Pos": ["Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher", "Not Pitcher"],
        "Age": [24, 28, 40, 22, 29, 33, 31, 26, 21, 36, 25, 31]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

When I `groupby` two keys `Team and Pos` what I get is:

```
print(df.groupby(['Team','Pos'])['Age'].count())

      Team          Pos  Age
0  Red Sox  Not Pitcher    3
1  Red Sox      Pitcher    3
2  Yankees  Not Pitcher    3
3  Yankees      Pitcher    3
```

I would like to have levels of `Pos` index into columns as such:

```
Team Not_Pitcher Pitcher
Red Sox 3 3
Yankees 3 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pd.crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Team,df.Pos)
Pos      Not Pitcher  Pitcher
Team                         
Red Sox            3        3
Yankees            3        3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can after `groupby` convert result to `DataFrame` then use [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) like below:

```
>>> res_df = df.groupby(['Team','Pos'])['Age'].count().reset_index(name= 'Count')
>>> res_df
      Team          Pos  Count
0  Red Sox  Not Pitcher      3
1  Red Sox      Pitcher      3
2  Yankees  Not Pitcher      3
3  Yankees      Pitcher      3

>>> res_df.pivot_table(index='Team', columns='Pos', values='Count')

Pos      Not Pitcher  Pitcher
Team                         
Red Sox            3        3
Yankees            3        3
```

By thanks @HenryYik the shortest answer can be:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Team', 'Pos']).size().unstack("Pos")
```

Comment: Or `df.groupby(['Team', 'Pos']).size().unstack("Pos")`.